# New to C, not sure why this simple program is segfaulting

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char *p = "26/02/1992";


    char *day;
    char *month;
    char *year;

    const char *delimiters = "/";

    day = strtok(p, delimiters);
    month = strtok (NULL, delimiters);
    year = strtok (NULL, delimiters);

    printf("%s  %s  %s\n", day, month, year);

    return 0;
}
```

Hey, I am just starting with C and trying out some things. Part of a program I am trying to create involves having to delimit strings. The above code is me trying to figure out how to do that. But, I keep getting segmentation faults when trying to run this but I have no idea why. I assume it is because I have done something wrong with pointers here, any help would be great

Is it related to the way I have defined the day, month, year pointers?

Comment: Where do you learn C from?

Comment: Try getting familiar with debuggers, they often can point you to the point of error (or close).

Comment: Right now out of the K&R C book;

And yeah I know I will need to use debuggers eventually, but it is just frustrating not being able to do something (seemingly) simple when I am just starting out

Comment: Its very likely that when the K&R book was written, this program would have worked.  Computers then were less rigid about read-only program data.  Now, it is a security problem where your program could get corrupted.

Comment: The K&R book is very much out of date. Do yourself a favor and invest in a good up-to-date book.

Comment: I am just starting my 3rd year of college and the reccomended/mandatory book IS the K&R one, I would be open to hearing of anything that is more modern and reccomended

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strtok` modifies the string as it parses it.

But you created a constant, literal string with `"26/02/1992"`, so it cannot be modified.
(it is a read-only piece of data built into your program).

To stop the seg-fault, you'll want to make a copy of the string in memory, where you are allowed to modify it.   `strdup` (String Duplicate) is a good function for this, but you'll need to `free` the memory when you're done with it.

```
char *p = strdup("26/02/1992");  // Make a copy of the literal string, but a copy you can modify.

[... do all your work  ...]

free(p);  // Free up your copy of the string.
```

Comment: This was a great answer, there is a reason why I used a character pointer, I am just trying to get to grips with some things just now. I will mark this as the answer in a few minutes when it is possible, thank you